# Present HTML that is stored in a PHP variable (WP)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, widget

new here but I haven't seen this question answered. I'm trying to present an HTML widget that is stored in a PHP variable on my site, but I can only get it to display the HTML and not render the widget itself.

Users of the site add hotel listings, and I've given them a field to enter the TripAdvisor widget HTML code as provided by TripAdvisor specific to each hotel. I'm able to store that HTML in a PHP variable called $review_widget for each hotel.

Now I want to present the HTML in $review_widget on the page for each hotel. I've tried just about everything, but echoing and everything else seems to just present the HTML code itself on the page instead of actually showing the widget.

```
$review_widget = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'review_widget' , true );

echo "$review_widget"; 
echo esc_html__( $review_widget , 'extretion' ); //extretion is the theme name
html_entity_decode($review_widget);
```

Any thoughts on how to get the widget displayed on page? Would prefer to stick to PHP & HTML as I'm not too familiar with JS.

If it helps, here is a sample of what the TripAdvisor HTML code looks like:

```
<div id="TA_selfserveprop100" class="TA_selfserveprop">
<ul id="lLaa2wD0G3bB" class="TA_links IWaxvm3Nn7e">
<li id="hrlz09yO" class="TyU4CYtn">
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.com/"><img src="https://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/branding/150_logo-11900-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor"/></a></li></ul></div>
<script src="https://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=selfserveprop&amp;uniq=100&amp;locationId=6575439&amp;lang=en_US&amp;rating=true&amp;nreviews=5&amp;writereviewlink=true&amp;popIdx=true&amp;iswide=false&amp;border=true&amp;display_version=2"></script>
```

Thanks kind people!

Comment: correct : `esc_html__( $review_widget , 'extretion' );` with `esc_html(__( $review_widget , 'extretion' ) );` to see if it's works, but I think it's useless to use __() function in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!

I was able to present the widget using this code:

```
$review_widget = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'review_widget' , true );
$review_widget_html = htmlspecialchars_decode($review_widget);
echo html_entity_decode($review_widget_html);
```